# Problem with traversing the same module second time

Tags: python-3.x

I have two .py files. The main_module is 'TS_File_analysis.py' and sub_module is 'Port_operations.py'.

Import sub_module in main_module.

```
from Port_operations import *

def main_menu():
    try:
        if r == 1:
            print()
        elif r == 2:
            search_cmd_output()
        elif r == 3:
            port_analyze_drops()
        elif r == 4:
            print('Exit out.! Good bye..:)')
            return
        else:
            print('Entered option was not valid.\n')
            main_menu()
    except ValueError as ex:
        print('Din\'t choose any option.\n')
        main_menu()
```

Import main_module in sub_module file.

```
from TS_File_analysis import main_menu

def port_analyze_drops():
    try:
        if int(r2) == 1:
            get_output_of_port_drops()  
        elif int(r2) == 2:
            get_output_of_port_errors()
        elif int(r2) == 3:
            del_res_file(temp_result2)
            main_menu()
        else:
            print('Entered option was not valid.\n')
            port_analyze_drops()
    except ValueError as ex:
        print('Din\'t choose any option.\n')
        port_analyze_drops()
    return
```

With the initial run, we can go from main_module to sub_module successfully and come back to main_module. Again if I want to go from main_module to sub_module it fails with the below traces.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Python\Source\Workspace\TS_File_Analysis\TS_File_analysis.py", line 151, in <module>
    main_menu()
  File "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Python\Source\Workspace\TS_File_Analysis\TS_File_analysis.py", line 95, in main_menu
    port_analyze_drops()
  File "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Python\Source\Workspace\TS_File_Analysis\Port_operations.py", line 20, in port_analyze_drops
    main_menu()
  File "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Python\Source\Workspace\TS_File_Analysis\TS_File_analysis.py", line 94, in main_menu
    port_analyze_drops.__module__
NameError: name 'port_analyze_drops' is not defined
```

Expectation is to switch from main_module to sub_module and vice versa as many times as you try to switch.

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippets provided it is hard to see the module hierarchy, import structure, calling tree, and namespace.  I would have to see the main_menu module to understand the import structure. If you can post that it would be helpful.

I can see two potential problems that may be confusing you.

First of all Python "import STAR" statements with 'import *' are totally frowned upon.  It is considered poor namespace management practice, because you can easily clobber other object names without realizing it.  It looks like you may be clobbering the main_menu function with your IMPORT STAR.  Please provide the full source code for the 'TS_File_analysis.py' file.

Second, it is better to structure your modules with a top-level main module e.g., "app_main.py" that imports the other supporting modules.  Your main_menu() function should be at the bottom of the app_main.py file and be run after the other modules are imported into it, not the other way around.  Submodules should not be importing the main module.